# Как динамически создать массив, не зная количества его элементов?

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы, malloc

В цикле читаю некоторый блок данных по частям различных размеров. Требуется учитывать размеры этих частей - думаю загонять их в массив. Как создать этот массив, если я не знаю сколько частей будет? Возможно ли реализовать такое в языке С стандартными методами?

Comment: В Си реализовать возможно всё :)

Comment: Можно сначала создать массив, а потом изменить его размер: посмотрите функцию realloc.

Comment: @mymedia почему этот вопрос (старый) предлагаете закрыть как дубликат более нового?

Comment: @alexolut, по нескольким причинам: а) не обязательно соблюдать хронологию при закрытии дубликатов; б) тот вопрос более конкретный, и мне удалось там привести рабочий пример (который вероятно можно адаптировать под эту задачу) в) и вообще тут же не ясно, что за блок данных имеется ввиду

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно будет использовать функцию `realloc`, определенную в заголовке `<stdlib.h>`, если  окажется, что выделенной памяти или количества элементов в динамически размещенном массиве недостаточно.

Другой подход - это использовать список, который вы либо сами напишите, либо возьмете чью-то готовую реализацию. В стандарте C списки не определяются.