# Как создать динамический массив?

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Хочу разобраться с динамическим выделением памяти в [c](/questions/tagged/c). Пришла в голову идея, попробовать сделать программу, которая спрашивает у пользователя имя и записывает ввод в массив типа `char`, но так чтобы массив сам выделял себе память. То есть без предварительного выделения вида `char name[30] = {0};`. Я ввожу имя *Магомед* и массив сам выделяет себе память на 7 символов. Как это сделать?

Comment: Плохо гуглили, ибо это - основы, которые есть в любом учебнике или справочнике. Вы хотите чтобы их здесь зачитали вам вслух? OK. 1) определем сколько памяти нужно выделить 2) выделяем её 3) в любом случае массив "сам себе" выделить ничего не может, это забота программиста.

Comment: Я понял. Выходит в С нельзя сделать так. "Не выделел память умер!"

Comment: Что значит "массив сам выделял себе память"?

Comment: Я уже понял что так не получится

Comment: То, что вы описываете, частный случай вектора. Делается элементарно.

Comment: Дайте пример кода!

Comment: По постановке задания это больше похоже на самую обычную [getline](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=getline&category=3&russian=0). Но то, что детали выделения памяти скрыты в её реализации, сути не меняет. Как и того, что в C нет никаких "динамических массивов".

Comment: @PinkTux, а она re-entrant?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как динамически создать массив, не зная количества его элементов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443426/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @alexolut Не надо закрывать этот вопрос как дубликат. Здесь ответ лучше. Лучше наоборот закрыть тот вопрос.

Comment: @Squidward стало интересно, а можно ли их закрыть взаимно :)

Comment: @alexolut Одно из закрытий произойдёт перым, после этого второе будет отменено.

Comment: @Squidward вот сейчас как раз и увидел это

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я бы взял указатель, длину и зарезервированную длину. Примерно

```
char * s = malloc(16);
int size = 16;
int used = 0;
```

И дальше читаем по одному символу. Как только вносим его в `s`, тут же увеличиваем `used`; как только `used == size`, так сразу увеличиваем массив раза в два:

```
s = realloc(s,size *= 2);
```

И все. Мы всегда знаем, сколько места имеется, сколько занято. Как в векторе в C++.

Comment: Дайте пример кода.

Answer (score 3):

Вот есть функция, которая прочитывает указанный файл посимвольно, пока не
встретит символ перевода строки или конец файла. Функция сама выделяет себе
память, а после использования строки буфер надо освободить с помощью `free`.
При нехватке памяти ввод обрывается и возвращаются считанные символы или `NULL`,
если не удалось ничего получить. Кроме того, для удобства чтения стандартного
ввода предлагается макрос.

```
char* get_full_line(FILE* f) {
    size_t capacity = 16;  // начальный объем массива
    char* str = malloc(capacity);
    size_t length = 0;
    if (!str) return NULL;

    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        if (length >= capacity) {
            char* p = realloc(str, capacity *= 4);  // коэфициент прироста
            if (!p) break;
            str = p;
        }
        str[length++] = ch;
    }
    str[length] = '\0';
    return str;
}
#define read_full_line() ( get_full_line(stdin) )
```

Answer (score 0):

А вот ещё подготовил пример приветствия. Используется функция
[**getline**(3)](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=getline&category=3) из расширения библиотеки языка си.

```
int main()
{
    printf("Ваше имя: ");

    char* name = NULL;
    size_t capacity = 0;
    ssize_t length = getline(&name, &capacity, stdin);

    if (length > 0 && name[length - 1] == '\n') {
        name[length - 1] = '\0';  // убирает перевод строки
    }
    printf("Привет, %s!\n", name ?: "незнакомец");
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Кроме того, в этом кусочке кода встречается ещё одно расширение GNU —
тренарный оператор без второго операнда. В этом случае, если первый операнд не
равен нулю, он будет взят в качестве результата, иначе берётся третий операнд.