# Динамический массив символов в C

Tags: c, массивы, строки, динамические-массивы

Как создать динамический массив символов (размер массива определяется в процессе ввода) в С?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792668/need-help-creating-a-dynamic-char-array-in-c

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610198/

Answer (score 2):

В самом языке Си нет динамических массивов, но функции стандартной библиотеки malloc, free и realloc позволяют реализовать массив переменного размера:

```
  int *mas = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);  // Создание массива из n элементов типа int
  ...
  mas = (int*)realloc(mas, sizeof(int) * m); // Изменение размера массива с n на m с сохранением содержимого
  ...
 free(mas); // Освобождение памяти после использования массива
```

Неудобство данного подхода состоит в необходимости вычислять размеры выделяемой памяти, применять явное преобразование типа и тщательно отслеживать время жизни массива (как и всегда при работе с динамически выделенной памятью в Си).

[Динамическое выделение памяти](https://prog-cpp.ru/c-alloc/) должно помочь.

Comment: При `realloc` не рекомендуется присваивать результат в тот же самый указатель. В случае ошибки реаллокации можно получить утечку.